# Verifying Green's Theorem on a simple closed curve involving area

Tags: solution-verification, greens-theorem

Given a simple closed curve $C$ which bounds a region $D$ and on which Green's theorem applies, I'm trying to show that $$ \text{Area}(D) = \int\limits_{C}x \ dy = - \int\limits_{C} y \ dx. \tag{1}$$
My attempt is as follows ; first assume $(1)$ is true. Since the contour integral is linear,
\begin{gather}
\int\limits_{C} x \ dy + \int\limits_{C} y \ dx = 0 \implies \int\limits_{C} x\ dy + y \ dx =0.
\end{gather}
Converting the last integral using Green's theorem and show it is equal to $0$ should imply that the initial assumption is correct.
\begin{gather}
\int\limits_{C} x \ dy +y \ dx = \int\limits_{C} Q \ dy + P \ dx \implies \iint\limits_{D} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \ dA = \iint\limits_{D}(1-1)\ dA = 0.
\end{gather}
Therefore the initial assumption $(1)$ is valid.
Can someone tell me if I went wrong somewhere as this reasoning seems quite simple , I feel like I must've missed some steps or made a wrong assumption.

Comment: You’ve shows that the two integrals are equal, but haven’t (yet) shown that either one is equal to the area of $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Green's Theorem  by taking $Q=x, P=0.$ You get first expression in the required identity and for the second, $Q=0,  P=-y$.   Use the fact $\iint_{D}  dA $= Area(D).